# Good UI to allow user to revert field to default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-interface

My web-based app allows users to override values in certain textboxes.  If they don't override the value, the system will display (and use) a default.

I would like to support a scenario where the user has overridden the value, but now wants to revert back to the system default value, but doesn't know what value to enter.  I would like to provide an intuitive UI for causing the system to revert the field's value back to its default.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Fields occur both on edit forms (where space is plentiful), as well as on edit grids (where space is scarce).

Requiring the user to clear the field is not an option, as sometimes the user's override is an empty value.  Would rather not use a keystroke, like Ctrl-Z or ESC.

Best thing I can think of is the user hovers over the field and a popup displays giving the user the option to use the system default.  I could use the same popup to capture/display a comment related to the override.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a 'rewind' type icon after a textbox (like an arrow in a circle that points backwards) where there is plenty of space to allow a user to revert to the default or original version.

Also used grey text to show the default - which disappears (using a keyup event) as the user overwrites.

If space is short your popup sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<input type="text" value="Enter text here, a space will clear it" 
onfocus="this.title='Clear field to revert to '+this.defaultValue" 
onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue; 
else this.defaultValue=this.value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest to look at how others have solved a UX problem before deciding on an answer. Ask yourself what applications (web or otherwise) have supplied default values and allowed you to revert back to them.

I think the problem you're likely trying to solve is not the interaction of reverting to default values, but rather, to inform users what the default values are. If this is the case I would lean away from a button and towards inline help.

Hope this helps.

-
Nik.ca